# Remove object from Array passing an instance of protocol

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a protocol called `IdeaListener`, and an array of elements which extends this protocol.

```
private var ideaListeners: [IdeaListener]
```

I want to create an extension in order to remove an object from the array given an instance of `IdeaProtocol`.

```
var myInstanceOfIdeaListener: IdeaListener
...
ideaListeners.removeObject(myInstanceOfIdeaListener)
```

I have found many solutions on the web but none of them were able to accept a protocol as parameter of the `removeObject` function.
In order to accomplish this, I wrote this extension:

```
extension Array {

   mutating func removeObject(object: AnyObject) -> Element? {

    for (index, objectToCompare) in self.enumerate() {
        if let to = objectToCompare as? AnyObject where to == object {
            return removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

But the compiler says

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'AnyObject' operands.

Why I cannot use == for comparing two `AnyObject`? How would you check if the array contains `object`?

Moreover, I want to improve this function, adding a type check at the beginning, in order to check if the type of `object` is actually the type of the elements in the array. I am not sure how to code this concept though. Something like this:

```
guard object is /*type of elements in array*/ else {
     return nil
}
```

How can I get the type of the elements in the array?

Comment: In order to use `==` you need `Equatable` conformance.  `AnyObject` does not have that.  For your cause you are better off with `===` operator that checks if two object references are actually the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this instead

```
    let a = ObjectOfProtocol()
    let b = ObjectNotOfProtocol()
    let c = [a,b]

    let d = c.filter { (x:AnyObject) -> Bool in

        return !x.conformsToProtocol(Protocol);
    }

    print("filtered array: \(d)") //should only show [ObjectNotOfProtocol]
```

this will remove all objects that conform to `Protocol` in the array

so instead of making an extension, can just use this filter

Could even add it as a [method extension to the Protocol itself](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID521), so you could go something like Protocol.filterFromArray(array) and it will return the array with all the objects of the Protocol filtered out if you want it to be just a method call and not have the filter written out each time